# deny access gust to .css and .js files in my website

Tags: nginx

How can I deny access gust to .css and .js files in my website.

I need this files to work normal in my website

but I don't want any one to know it!

how can I do it?

I'm useing "NGINX"

thx.

Comment: This question is being voted for closure because the author does not show a level of technical understanding or appropriate due diligence in researching the topic that the community judges as being a minimum barrier to participate.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to prevent .CSS and .JS files from being viewed by your users without breaking your website's functionality. They can be minified/obfuscated to some extent, but any determined user will be able to figure that out.